# Inspect variable of child Python process without modifying child

Tags: python, flask

Context: I have a parent process which spawns a child process that runs a Flask web server. I require the parent process to acquire a reference to a particular global variable stored inside Flask: the Flask application object. NB: I don't want the current request context, I require the flask `app` variable that is used to start the web server, as I want the parent process to register some `before_request` handlers on it.

I cannot modify the child process to handle the communication using something like `multiprocessing`.

Is there a way for me to easily get the value of this variable within the parent? Does Python support such a mechanism? Would I have to use something like ptrace in order to inspect the child's memory and somehow find the  address of the variable I'm interested in?